# QGIS - Default Date Formats

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, date, datetime

I manage a fairly large estate of QGIS installs in the UK and am looking to set the default date formats to the uk dd/mm/yyyy format from our MSSQL data warehouse.  Its set and works correctly in the database but QGIS defaults to YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.  Is there an option anywhere for me to change the format of this display date globally?

I am aware I can do it via widgets however we have over 1000 datasets in the warehouse and any local datasets the users have would still be affected by the default date formatting.

Comment: why not fix MSSQL to use ISO date formats?

Comment: Our SQL estate is managed by a 3rd party who set the standards and wont consider a change like that as it does not meet their "standards"...  We have tried